# Identifying multiple keywords in a sentence using python

Tags: python

I have seen that using the "term" variable you can identify keywords in a sentence, but I was wondering if there was a way to have it check for multiple things using the term rule. For example if you were looking for hello it would pick up on **hello! hello. hello?** etc. Any way of doing this all in one go or would I have to split it up?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Please provide sample input and desired output. As it is not clear what you desire.

Comment: What is the "term variable?" You can't expect people to guess about what you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really clear but from what I understand you probably will need some sort of regex like ^hello(.*)